# Arrange Object key in javascript (string, number in string)

Tags: javascript, object

I have issue for sorting Object key, I have dynamic object and I want to do sorting the object like

```
let list = [
  {
    "name": "Ann",
    "01": "P",
    "02": "S",
    "03": "X",
    "04": "P",
    "05": "S",
    "06": "X",
    "10": "P",
    "11": "S",
    "12": "X",
    "13": "P",
    "14": "S",
    "15": "X"
  },
  {
    "name": "Unn",
    "01": "X",
    "02": "B",
    "03": "O",
    "04": "X",
    "05": "X",
    "06": "B",
    "10": "O",
    "11": "X",
    "12": "X",
    "13": "B",
    "14": "O",
    "15": "X"
  }
]
```

I read and Try at [W3Doc](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/javascript/how-to-sort-javascript-object-by-key.html) and using this [lodash-keyarrange](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash-keyarrange)

but the result was not what I wanted,the result is sorting in weird way like

```
{
  "10": "Ann",
  "11": "Ann",
  "12": "Ann",
  "13": "Ann",
  "14": "Ann",
  "15": "Ann",
  "01": "Ann",
  "02": "Ann",
  "03": "Ann",
  "04": "Ann",
  "05": "Ann",
  "06": "Ann",
  "name": "Ann"
}
```

first try with (false result)

```
const sortObj = (obj) => {
  return Object.keys(obj).sort().reduce((result, key) =>{
    result[key] = obj[key]
    return result
  }, {})
}
const list = {
  "name": "Ann",
  "01": "Ann",
  "02": "Ann",
  "03": "Ann",
  "04": "Ann",
  "05": "Ann",
  "06": "Ann",
  "10": "Ann",
  "11": "Ann",
  "12": "Ann",
  "13": "Ann",
  "14": "Ann",
  "15": "Ann"
}
const arr = sortObj(list)
console.log(arr)
```

And without sort is also same result

```
const list = {
  "name": "Ann",
  "01": "Ann",
  "02": "Ann",
  "03": "Ann",
  "04": "Ann",
  "05": "Ann",
  "06": "Ann",
  "10": "Ann",
  "11": "Ann",
  "12": "Ann",
  "13": "Ann",
  "14": "Ann",
  "15": "Ann"
}
console.log(list)
```

I need this format to insert data to `vue-json-excel` for now the data look like this

[Result vue-json-excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjW90.png)

I already try with hardcoded initial value, but when go to console it become sorted, anyway to make this not auto sorted.? or sorted with costum value with my need.?

Thank you

Comment: convert them to `int` while sorting them

Comment: Objects are not sortable. Use an array of key-value pairs if you need an order. You seem to be running into a problem with integer keys being separated from other keys, which cannot be changed.

Comment: `Map` suits your use case

Comment: @bergi any exsample that I can see to use array key-value pairs for that plugin

Answer (score 0):

Updated: you should use the `json_fields` from the `vue-json-excel` lib

```
data: {
json_fields: {
     "name": "name",
     "last": "last",
    "01": "01",
    "02": "02",
    "03": "03",
    "04": "04",
    "05": "05",
    "06": "06",
    "10": "10",
    "11": "11",
    "12": "12",
    "13": "13",
    "14": "14",
    "15": "15"
},
json_data: [{
 "10": "Ann",
 "11": "Ann",
 "12": "Ann",
 "13": "Ann",
 "14": "Ann",
 "15": "Ann",
 "01": "Ann",
 "02": "Ann",
 "03": "Ann",
 "04": "Ann",
 "05": "Ann",
 "06": "Ann",
 "name": "Ann",
 "last": "Ann"
}],
json_meta: [
  [
    {
      key: "charset",
      value: "utf-8",
    },
  ],
 ],
},
```

Let me know if this helps:

```js
const va = {
  "10": "Ann",
  "11": "Ann",
  "12": "Ann",
  "13": "Ann",
  "14": "Ann",
  "15": "Ann",
  "01": "Ann",
  "02": "Ann",
  "03": "Ann",
  "04": "Ann",
  "05": "Ann",
  "06": "Ann",
  "name": "Ann",
  "last": "Ann"
}
const keyOrder = [
  "name",
  "01",
  "02",
  "03",
  "04",
  "05",
  "06",
  "10",
  "11",
  "12",
  "13",
  "14",
  "15",
];
const out = new Map()
keyOrder.forEach((k) => {
  out.set(k, va[k])
});
out.forEach((value, key) => console.log(key, value));
```

Comment: At this point he could just be using arrays for everything

Comment: I update the question and also add the picture, maybe you can help me solve this issue

Comment: you should use `json_fields` in the `vue-json-excel` package